# How to make a link between Javascript put in the HTML code with Style.css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tizen

Creating an application allowing to calculate the heart rate thanks to a connected watch. I use the Tizen studio software to make this project and I used the model "HeartRateSensor". I then modified lines to make him correspond with my project. I need to post the hour and for it I integrated an end of code into Javascript in the HTML code:

My question is how to personalize this hour? (Position on the screen).
How to make a link of this code in Javascript put in the HTML code with Style.css?

Comment: you might want to add tizen to the list of tags, since this seems to be a question related to this software rather than general question about JS and CSS

Comment: `document.write('<span class="time">',today.getHours(), "h", today.getMinutes(),'</span>');`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an empty  element in your HTML. Set an ID for it.
For example div id="hours"

Then edit first line of your JS code to
var today = document.getElementById("hours");

Then in your style.css you can edit the "#hours"

Answer (score 0):

The same way as with any HTML based project. Add CSS files and reference those in your index.html.

Alternatively you can put style declarations in your DOM elements, such as `style="background-color: black"` and so on.

There is no difference between Tizen and any other HTML page with respect to this question. If you do not know how to use CSS, then read up on it. Google is your friend.